# How to use wavesurfer.js in React (Next.js)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, wavesurfer.js

I'm trying to render audio files using wavesurfer.js in my react app. I'm a noob and I'm wondering why I'm getting a ***"Container element not found"*** message all the time.
I found, that in react app we should use refs for container, but it did not help me.

To write this code I used examples from several resources:

https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/methods.html

https://dev.to/jamland/audio-player-with-wavesurfer-js-react-1g3b

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-ctankx?file=pages%2Findex.js

Thank you in advance!

```html
const formWaveSurferOptions = (ref) => ({
  container: ref,
  waveColor: '#ffc600',
  progressColor: '#c79b03',
  cursorColor: '#c79b03',
  barWidth: 3,
  barRadius: 3,
  responsive: true,
  height: 53,
  overflow: 'hidden',
  normalize: true,
  partialRender: true,
});

export function Player({ className, id, audio, audioPlayId, setAudioPlayId, ...props }: PlayerProps): JSX.Element {
  const waveformRef = useRef(null);
  const wavesurfer = useRef(null);
  const [playing, setPlay] = useState(false);
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0.5);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  // To pause all other audios if plays current component
  useEffect(() => {
    if (audioPlayId) {
      if (audioPlayId != id) {
        setPlay(false)
        wavesurfer.current.pause()
      }
    }
  }, [audioPlayId])

  // create new WaveSurfer instance
  // On component mount and when url changes
  useEffect(() => {
    import('wavesurfer.js').then((m) => {
      const WaveSurfer = m.default;
      setPlay(false);

      const options = formWaveSurferOptions(waveformRef.current);
      wavesurfer.current = WaveSurfer?.create(options);


      wavesurfer.current.load(
        audio
      );

      wavesurfer.current.on('ready', function () {
        // https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/methods.html
        // wavesurfer.current.play();
        // setPlay(true);

        // make sure object stillavailable when file loaded
        if (wavesurfer.current) {
          wavesurfer.current.setVolume(volume);
          setVolume(volume);
        }

        setIsLoaded(true)
      });
    });

    // Removes events, elements and disconnects Web Audio nodes.
    // when component unmount
    return () => { wavesurfer?.current?.destroy() }
  }, []);



  const handlePlayPause = (e): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    setPlay(!playing);
    wavesurfer.current.playPause();
    setAudioPlayId(id)
  };


  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <div className={styles.palyer_container}>
        <div id={styles.waveform} ref={waveformRef} />
        {isLoaded ?
          <div className="controls">
            <Button appearance="container" onClick={handlePlayPause}>{!playing ? <PlayIcon /> : <PauseIcon />}</Button>
          </div> : <Loader />}
      </div>
    </div >
  );
}
```

**EDITED:**  all related code

Comment: what happens if you import wavesurfer.js at the top?

Comment: What element are you assigning the `wavesurfer` ref to? Can you please add the rest of the component's code?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves) Edited

Comment: David, in next js we should import tis lib dynamically

Comment: You seem to be using two refs? Where does `waveformRef` come from? Also, where does `audio` come from? Please include all the relevant code.

Comment: I've added code [juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves)

Comment: Do you have multiple players on the same page? On latest wavesurfer.js version, the only issue I could reproduce with your code and using multiple players is in `wavesurfer.current.pause()`. That will throw an error for the players that aren't currently playing on initial load. You can just change it to `wavesurfer.current?.pause()` to avoid the issue. Is that your problem?

Comment: did you ever manage to get this working within next.js?